# how to display articles by user in django?

Tags: django, view, models

I have article models:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(editable=True)    
    whopost = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
```

and I have userprofile models:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    info1 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="")
```

I try to do a relation between a user and article so I know who created an article. It would allow me to display articles by logged-in user.

So,

I try following in my article views:

```
def articles(request):

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    user_articles = Article.objects.filter(whopost_id=request.user.id)
    latest_articles = Article.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:10]

    #display articles in order by date
    #args['articles'] = latest_articles

    #display articles in order by user
    args['articles'] = user_articles

    args['language'] = language
    args['session_language'] = session_language

    return render(request, 'articles.html', args)
```

I have three users created:

user A
user B
user C

in my userprofile_userprofile users have following

```
id | user_id
1  | 1
2  | 13
3  | 14
```

in my auth_user users have following

```
id 
1
13
14
```

So, I get values 1, 2, 3 instead of 1, 13, 14.

What should I change in my code to get values 1, 13, 14 and not 1, 2, 3  ?

Furthermore, the 2nd part of the question is:

How to display article by user in order by date ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a values() command in your queryset.

```
user_articles = Article.objects.filter(whopost=request.user.userprofile.id).values('whopost').order_by('-pub_date')
```

Comment: I get an AttributeError "'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'fields'"

Comment: It does not display now "title" and "body" of the article. Please see the image uploaded: http://i.imgur.com/dlVhVRJ.png

Comment: you can add the fields you want to display in the values() command. This way you display only what you need. eg. values('whopost', 'title', 'body') and so on.

Comment: how different is (whopost=request.user.useprofile.id).values() from (whopost__id = request.user.useprofile.id) ? I do not know if should I access it with whopost or whopost__id or whopost_id. How do I know it ?

Comment: whopost__id is comparing just the id. wheras just using whopost compares the instance of the object. it would save an extra call to check the id of whopost for comparison

Comment: Ok. I almost have it. So, how do you know there is 'whopost' value so you include it in values('whopost') ? I did relation in my Article model: whopost = model.ForeignKey(UserProfile) and UserProfile has not got whopost value. It is just a bit unclear to me.

Comment: I am not sure if i understood your question correctly here! The values('whopost') will give you the meta values of your UserProfile. If you want to get the User data, you can do values('whopost__user__id'), which will return you the id's from you r user table

Comment: I can display articles with all its attributes by user if I do following user_articles = Article.objects.filter(whopost=request.user.userprofile.id).order_by('-pub_date'). I do not understand why .values() is needed by I need to read about it. Thank you for all your help and answer.

Answer (score 2):

**First part of your question:**

To get `userprofile` IDs instead of `user` IDs just access your one-to-one relationship to `UserProfile` like this:

```
userprofile_id = request.user.userprofile.id
```

**Second part of your question:**

To order a specific User's articles by date you simply do the following:

```
articles_by_date = Article.objects.filter(
    whopost__id=request.user.userprofile.id
).order_by('-pub_date')
```

Comment: to answer your 1st question: yes, i get same funcionality in both whopost_id and whopost__id. I have followed your advice with userproile_id = request.user.userprofile.id and modified filter as follows: "user_articles = Article.objects.filter(whopost__id = request.user.userprofile.id)" and it works ! Although, I am still not sure if should I do _id or __id.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups) single underscore only works with ForeignKeys. For all other lookups you'll have to use the double underscore. Woah, I've learned something today :)

Comment: So, it sounds like I should use single underscore because whopost=models.ForeignKey(UserProfile). is it correct ?

Comment: Yes this is correct. You're doing a lookup on a `ForeignKey` here (`whopost_id=...`) so it works with single underscore. If whopost was something else (for example a `ManyToManyField`) you would have to use double underscores (`whopost__id=...)`. I hope it's clear now :)

Comment: Thank you for all your help with my question. I have decided to use Roger Feder's answer as most helpful only because he was first. Thank you anyway !